# Modelica Frequency/Time Domain combined equations

Tags: modelica

Im creating a model of a rather complex electric circuit in modelica. 
I want to find out how to include "s" equations (I mean frequency domain equations) in the model. 
Of course I may transform the expresion to time and use modelicas internal "time" variable, but I not sure this is optimal way to complete my model. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In modelica you can implement a block to switch from one domain to the other and then develop the equation in the proper domain. To do this I suggest you to look at [this article](http://blog.xogeny.com/blog/fourier-analysis/) written by Michael Tiller.
In general it depends on the type of equations you have to implement, whether it is more convenient to write the equations in time or frequency domain, although you have to take into account that going from time domain to frequency domain you are always introducing some semplifications because of the sampling. Therefore if the equations rewritten in time are not too stiff or if you are not introducing too non-linearities, and if you have a big range of frequencies in your systems, I think it is better to rewrite the equations in the time domain.

I hope this helps,
Marco

Answer (score 1):

It is the transfer function you are describing, right? If so, check out [Modelica_LinearSystems2](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica_LinearSystems2.UsersGuide.GettingStarted.LinearSystemDataStructures.html)